# Bootstrap 4 table row shadow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, shadow

Is there a way to show a shadow around table rows with bootstrap 4?

I tried the following, but the shadow only appears around the outside of the table:

```
<table>
<TR class="shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
</TR>
<TR class="shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
</TR>
<TR class="shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
  <TD>Table Cell</TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/na6ohL0j/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `shadow` class from your html and add the following in your css:

```
tr { 
box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Though this pushes all the row cells next to each other

Comment: I've checked again, and my table rows seems fine? It looks exactly like the bottom part (as you require) https://codepen.io/mrcj101111/pen/WPZvQw

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact but somewhat close to your desired output. Try This:

```css
tr {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.15)!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Table Head</th>
          <th scope="col">Table Head</th>
          <th scope="col">Table Head</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
          <td>Table Cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution is to use an another table. And then apply shadow for it.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="w-100">
        <TR class=" bg-white rounded">
          <td>
            <table class="my-3 shadow w-100">
              <tr>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </TR>
        <TR class="bg-white rounded">
          <td>
            <table class="my-3 shadow w-100">
              <tr>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </TR>
        <TR class="bg-white rounded">
          <td>
            <table class="my-3 shadow w-100">
              <tr>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
                <TD class="p-3">Table Cell</TD>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </TR>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Only problem with this is that it messes up the column alignment with the original table columns.  Is there any way to do this with bootstrap without another table?

Comment: You can do so, but you need to override a lot of properties which might cause unintended bugs.  Could you post the original table columns too? The alignment can be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0em 1em;
  padding: 0 2em 1em 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It always helps to add an explanation. Code only answers are not always helpful to those who are learning.